# How to pass a variable from one controller to another laravel

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass a variable from a controller to some other controller. I'm doing it like this-

**SomeController**

```
public function index(){
  $var = 'variable';
  return redirect()->route('toAnotherController')->with('var', $var);
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/anotherController', 'AnotherController@index')->name('toAnotherController');
```

**Another Controller**

```
public function index(){
  echo $var;
}
```

But, this is giving an error "Undefined variable $var".
What is going wrong here?
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you:

```
Route::get('/anotherController/{var}', 'AnotherController@index')->name('toAnotherController');

public function index($var){
  echo $var;
}
```

Then use Redirect:

```
  return redirect()->route('toAnotherController',[$var]);
```

Good Luck ~~~

Comment: Bare in mind the `{var}` in the routes means it is *required*. You can specify optional parameters as `{var?}` in case this is optional.

Comment: I had also tried that method to pass the data, but the problem i was having was in the redirection (while passing the data). It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is not too late. But I am sure this might help somebody one day!!!
In your **SomeController**
Add this instance **public $attributes;**
Add the variable you want to pass to another controller with this

```
$request->attributes->add(['var' => $request->var]);
```

You can equally resolve it with the code below on the (**Another Controller**)controller where you needed it

```
$var= app('request')->get('var');
```

N:B - Laravel 5.7. I am not sure of earlier versions

Comment: This is the one I've been looking for. Thanks <3